# Admin sidebar customization

Tags: admin-menu

My new clients wordpress site does not have plugins, appearance or any of the other default items in the admin sidebar. Can anyone tell me how I get those to appear. The site is being run in a sub-directory of the main site. It has it's own wordpress installation. The theme is rttheme16 from themeforest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Troubleshoot](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-34-master-list?replies=5) your WordPress installation. Unless you detect what piece of code in the theme has a problem, there's nothing we can do. That's a *premium* theme, with closed code, and that does have its own support channels. ..... Oh, and welcome to WPSE!

Answer (score 1):

This may sound silly but are you sure you have administrator permissions? (Logged in with an account with Administrator privileges.)

If you are sure you have the correct permissions, you may also want to check with the original theme developer to see if there are white label admin features enabled within the theme.  You will need your client's login to communicate with the developer of a purchased theme on ThemeForest.

White label options would be most commonly located in the theme's functions.php file (or a similar named file - so check your includes) and would look similar to the example in the below link:

http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-remove-menus-in-wordpress-dashboard

Comment: I agree with Christi. At least that would be the first place that I would check. It sounds like the user account that you are using to log in to admin panel is less than an administrator, such as an editor or author. The theme or the fact that its located in a sub directory of the main site should have no bearing on the admin menu structure.